# JQuery: replace array value using .replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

for example i have an array like below:

```
[
    "May 30, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 6, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 13, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 20, 2015 12:00:00 AM"
]
```

and i'd like to use `replace()` to convert all `12:00:00 AM` is into `empty` so it become

```
["May 30, 2015 ", "Jun 6, 2015", "Jun 13, 2015", "Jun 20, 2015"]
```

How may i do that?

Comment: Did you try anything ? What's the problem ?

Comment: you need this ? https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5479/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `for` to iterate array items and replace content of them.

```js
var arr = [
    "May 30, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 6, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 13, 2015 12:00:00 AM", 
    "Jun 20, 2015 12:00:00 AM"
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" 12:00:00 AM", "");
}

console.log(arr);
```